# internal server error after submitting a form flask,sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I inserted new record from the form, the data will be successfully added into database, but it will show an error page "INTERNAL SERVER ERROR", if I manually back to my form page and refresh i can see the inserted data, but i want it refresh it self and don't show the error page, how to do that?

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import sqlite3

app = Flask(__name__)

db_name = 'crm.db'

@app.route('/')
def index():
   title = "主页"
   return render_template("index.html", title = title)

@app.route('/company', methods = ['POST','GET'])
def company():
   if request.method == 'GET':
       title = "公司"
       company_db = query_company()
       return render_template("company.html", title = title, company_db = company_db)
   else:
       insert_company()

def query_company():
   connection = sqlite3.connect(db_name)
   c = connection.cursor()
   c.execute("""SELECT * FROM company""")
   company_db = c.fetchall()
   return company_db

def insert_company():
   connection = sqlite3.connect(db_name)
   c = connection.cursor()
   query = 'INSERT INTO company(company_full_name, company_short_name) VALUES(?,?)'
   cfn = request.form.get("cfn")
   csn = request.form.get("csn")
   company_info = (cfn,csn)
   c.execute(query, company_info)
   connection.commit()
   connection.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug = True)
```

Comment: In the function `company` does replacing `insert_company` with `insert_company()` help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the company function to ...

```
def company():
   if request.method == 'POST':
       insert_company()

   title = "公司"
   company_db = query_company()
   return render_template("company.html", title = title, company_db = company_db)
```

This way the new data will first be inserted and then all rows will be automatically refreshed

Comment: oh, i forgot to return.